# Unable to access Seq elements and return entire Seq as Json

Tags: json, scala

So I am extremely new to Scala and seem to be doing something horribly wrong for a simple logic. 
I need to query database to get all the WebsiteTemplates.
I am then trying to access the first element of the sequence (simply for practice) but keep getting the **ClassCastException - [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to models.WebsiteTemplate**. Next, I would want to return the entire Seq obtained as Json. Tried Json.arr() but won't work. Searched but none matches the exact use case strangely. Here is relevant the code -

**WebsiteController**

```
@Singleton
class WebsiteTemplateController @Inject()(websiteTemplateDAO: WebsiteTemplateDAO, db: DB) extends Controller{

  def index = Action.async {
    implicit request => db.withTransaction() {
      implicit em => {
        try {

          val templates: Seq[WebsiteTemplate] = websiteTemplateDAO.findAll()
          val template = templates(0)

          Logger.info("The size is " + template.name)
          Future(Ok(Json.obj(
            "message" -> "Success"
          )))
        } catch {

          case e: Exception =>
            e.printStackTrace()
            Future(InternalServerError(s"Lag gaye"))
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**WebsiteDAOImpl**

```
@ImplementedBy(classOf[WebsiteTemplateDAOImpl])
trait WebsiteTemplateDAO extends DAO[WebsiteTemplate]{
  def findAll()(implicit em: EntityManager): Seq[WebsiteTemplate]
}

@Singleton
class WebsiteTemplateDAOImpl @Inject()(db: DB) extends DAOImpl(classOf[WebsiteTemplate]) with WebsiteTemplateDAO{

  override def findAll()(implicit em: EntityManager): Seq[WebsiteTemplate] = {

    val query = em.createQuery(s"SELECT idint, name FROM WebsiteTemplate")
    db.executeQuery(query)
  }
}
```

**DAOImpl**

```
trait DAO[T] {
  def findById(id:String)(implicit em:EntityManager) : Option[T]
  def create : T
}

class DAOImpl[T](cls:Class[T]) extends DAO[T] {
  def findById(id: String)(implicit em: EntityManager): Option[T] = {
    val query = em.createQuery(s"Select c from ${cls.getName} as c where c.id=:id")
    query.setParameter("id",id)
    val list = query.getResultList
    if (list.nonEmpty) {
      Option(list(0).asInstanceOf[T])
    } else {
      None
    }
  }

  override def create: T = {
    cls.newInstance()
  }
}
```

**WebsiteTemplate**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "templates")
@EntityListeners(Array(classOf[SetForeignKeyOnSave]))
class WebsiteTemplate{

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  @BeanProperty
  var intid: java.lang.Integer = _

  /*@Transient
  override var id: String = _*/

  @BeanProperty
  @Column(name = "name")
  var name: String = _
}
```

A bit more explanation of my problem. On getting the type of templates(0) using `getClass()` method, it shows as `[Ljava.lang.Object` whereas I expect it to be of type `WebsiteTemplate`.

Comment: Did you read https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson ?

Comment: You need to add your own `Writes` for your type `WebsiteTemplate`.

Comment: Got it. Having `Writes` is the way forward.

Comment: But what about the simple logging using `template.name`?

Comment: You don't see that logging being printed?

Comment: Nope. Getting this `ClassCastException - [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to models.WebsiteTemplate` on the line above it :(

Comment: What's `DAOImpl`? What does it do?

Comment: A class which has basic methods like `getById()` implemented.

Comment: Could you add code for `WebsiteTemplateDAO` and `DAOImpl`?

Comment: Code has been updated

Comment: What's the type of `val query = ???`? What version of Play are you using? Are you also using anorm? Are you using JPA?

Comment: val query type is QueryImpl(as expected), Play version is 2.4.4, using JPA.
Also added the model code

Comment: Also, if you could add your imports on your code... it would make things easier for me to reproduce. Plus you mix Java and Scala. Is there a particular reason for that?

Comment: I would recommend you to stop using Hibernate or JPA stuff with Scala. Try Slick for database access! It is much better and simpler to use!